# I would like to implement a LinkedList data structure in JS

Tags: javascript

```
var MyLinkedList = function(val) {
    this.head = {
    val: val,
    next: null
    };
this.length = 1;
};

MyLinkedList.prototype.addAtHead = function(value) {
    var newNode = {
        val: value}
        newNode.next = this.head
    this.length++
    return newNode;
};
var test = new MyLinkedList(3);
var test2 = test.addAtHead(12);
var test3 = test2.addAtHead(4)
```

The first two tests are working for me, but when I try to add another node to the head in test3 an error occurs: "TypeError: test2.addAtHead is not a function". I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Why do you expect `test2` (which is the returned `newNode` object) to have that method?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it by returning `this` and pointing `head` to `newNode`

```js
var MyLinkedList = function(val) {
  this.head = {
    val: val,
    next: null
  };
  this.length = 1;
};

MyLinkedList.prototype.addAtHead = function(value) {
  var newNode = {
    val: value,
  }
  newNode.next = this.head;
  this.head = newNode;
  this.length++;
  return this;
};
var test = new MyLinkedList(3);
console.log(test);
var test2 = test.addAtHead(12);
console.log(test2);
var test3 = test2.addAtHead(4);
console.log(test3);
```

Comment: @FanniRákosi as you've added `addAtHead` to `MyLinkedList`, you've to return that so that new variable has that function available, you can try hitting on `Run code snippet` to verify the output and if it solves your problem, you can accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `addAtHead()`, you aren't creating an instance of your `MyLinkedList`, you are simply creating an object with similar properties. You need to actually create an instance of it so it'll have the method.

I think your general approach might be a bit off. You need each link in your list to be an instance of `MyLinkedList`. It looks like you may be creating something more akin to an array.

There are two approaches to creating a linked list. The first is that each link in the list is the same and you just keep track of head and current directly:

```js
function LinkedList(value) {
  return { value, next: null };
}

const head = new LinkedList(5);
head.next = LinkedList(8);
head.next.next = LinkedList(3);

let current = head;
while (current) {
  console.log(current.value);
  current = current.next;
}
```

If you then want to wrap that up into something that manages the tracking stuff for you, you'll need a second class:

```js
function LinkedListNode(value) {
  return { value, next: null };
}

function LinkedList(firstValue) {
  this.head = new LinkedListNode(firstValue);
  this.current = this.head;
  this.tail = this.current;
  this.length = 1;
}

LinkedList.prototype.add = function(val) { 
  this.tail.next = new LinkedListNode(val); 
  this.tail = this.tail.next;
  this.length++;
};

LinkedList.prototype.rewind = function() { this.current = this.head; }
LinkedList.prototype.next = function() { this.current = this.current.next; }

const linkedList = new LinkedList(5);
linkedList.add(3);
linkedList.add(5);
linkedList.add(8);

while(linkedList.current) {
  console.log(linkedList.current.value);
  linkedList.next();
}
```

If you want to add something at the head, that would really be an insert where you need to put the previous `head.next` as the `next` to the new element:

```js
function LinkedListNode(value) {
  return { value, next: null };
}

function LinkedList(firstValue) {
  this.head = new LinkedListNode(firstValue);
  this.current = this.head;
  this.tail = this.current;
  this.length = 1;
}

LinkedList.prototype.add = function(val) { 
  this.tail.next = new LinkedListNode(val); 
  this.tail = this.tail.next;
  this.length++;
};

LinkedList.prototype.rewind = function() { this.current = this.head; }
LinkedList.prototype.next = function() { this.current = this.current.next; }

LinkedList.prototype.insertAtHead = function(val) {
  const newNode = new LinkedListNode(val);
  newNode.next = this.head.next;
  this.head.next = newNode;
}

const linkedList = new LinkedList(1);
linkedList.insertAtHead(2);
linkedList.insertAtHead(3);
linkedList.insertAtHead(4);

while(linkedList.current) {
  console.log(linkedList.current.value);
  linkedList.next();
}
```

Notice how except for the first value, with that function all of the values are backwards (which is why it is a little weird to have a function named `addAtHead`).

Comment: thank you for your answer! this was a leetcode excercise, they named the function.